# UserPicker changes not registered

Tags: google-app-maker

I have to edit two objects of the same datasource. I'm using UserPicker widget to change the person attached to the objects (picking up just the email).

In the beginning I have:

- ObjectA { owner: owner1@sample.com }
- ObjectB { owner: owner1@sample.com }

After this, I want to change the owner of ObjectA to Owner2. This works out fine.

Then, using the same edit widget (with a different datasource item), I want to change the owner of ObjectB to Owner2, also. However, this does not work out, since the UserPicker widget does not register the change from Owner1 -> Owner2. This happens because the UserPicker has stored the value Owner2 from the first change I made (so to the app it seems that I'm making a change Owner2 -> Owner2 .. onChange not triggered, datasource not saved).

I've tried altering the widget value on attach, but I've yet to get it to work. Is this something that should be fixed on the AppMaker side, too?

Thanks for your help, please ask clarifying questions if you don't understand.

Comment: It looks like a bug, feel free to report it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192783&template=833410

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just in case anyone else is having this problem while the fixing of the bug is still under work (I reported the bug though). This is how I dealt with it:

UserPicker widget onDetach:

```
if(widget.datasource.item.OwnerEmail !== widget.value) {
  widget.datasource.item.OwnerEmail = widget.value;
}
```

This makes sure that the value change is saved into the record anyway, when the widget is being detached.

However, this solution is missing the automatic validation (which is done in UserPicker widget by default). So you might need to make sure that the entered value is actually an email, in this solution there is no guarantee of that.

There are probably better ways to do this, but this is just a quick fix I came up with.